# Vertex AI endpoints - dataset creation after every batch prediction

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, mlops

Vertex AI endpoints provide Batch Prediction functionality that is very useful to perform predictions on a large amount of data.

However, every time I make a new batch prediction the endpoint creates a new Dataset inside BigQuery. This is very uncomfortable because if I make 100 batch predictions per day, I will obtain 100 new Datasets inside BigQuery.

Is there a way to make all predictions converge inside the same Dataset? I mean, each prediction is a new Table inside a specific Dataset of BigQuery.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Another option is to [upvote the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you feel it is useful for you. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to make Vertex predictions in the same Dataset you need, to specify the [`Dataset ID` in the `OUTPUT_URI`](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/tabular-data/classification-regression/get-batch-predictions#api:-bigquery:%7E:text=bqDatasetId.bqTableId-,OUTPUT_URI,-%3A%20Reference%20to%20the) in your Batch Prediction.

```
bq://bqprojectId.bqDatasetId
```

If you just specify the `Project ID`, Vertex AI creates a new output dataset for you. Specifying the `dataset ID` is an optional resource.

You can also specify the `table ID` but this is not always the best.

```
bq://bqprojectId.bqDatasetId.bqTableId
```

You can see in this [document](https://googleapis.dev/python/aiplatform/1.3.0/aiplatform.html?highlight=batch_predict#google.cloud.aiplatform.Model.batch_predict) the destination prefix while doing a batch prediction.